# smarty template doesn't load on CentOS system but works on localhost

Tags: php, smarty

I'm working on php based open source eFront elearning system where the template engine is smarty. Problem is when I uploads the whole site on Web server which is CentOS based, doesn't load some teamplates where there are no problem in localhost which is Windows based. There are neither any errors nor shows any thing, It stopped after load few HTML. Can any one give any solution? Is it server related issue?

Comment: I'm sure PHP errors are being supressed - most likely the compiled templates directory doesn't exist and/or is not writable. - check that first?

Answer (score 0):

Most common problem when migrating from WINDOWS to Other OS, I have faced and Solved is the **Case Sensitivity**. Windows is case insensitive while CentOS is Case-sensitive.

when finding directory or file in windows, it simply ignores Case while Linux DON'T.

Comment: if the issue is Case-sensitive than there should show some errors on CentOS? I dont get any errors when page stop loading though the error reporting is on.

Answer (score 0):

At last I got the reason, on the live server, the smarty couldn't create cache folder due to write permission. When the permission given the site looks okay.